# Why in Azure DevOps build pipeline refers to a different commit during the pull request checks?

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull-request

In Azure DevOps platform, my ***Pull Request*** has the last commit named `dbbdc012`
but the build policy validation points to a completely different commit named `3fa5v161`

During the build pipeline execution I expected Azure DevOps checked out my pull request last published commit.

After locally `git fetch --all` i tryed to `git checkout 3fa5v16175fcd23f5391fe8880cf8d36cc54e257` in order to verify what is this commit

It raised the following error

*fatal: reference is not a tree: 3fa5v16175fcd23f5391fe8880cf8d36cc54e257*

what happen in the pull request build pipeline?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have a build pipeline set up to verify pull requests, the pipeline will not just build the latest commit on the branch of the pull request but it will instead merge that pull request in with the target branch first and run the pipeline on that result.

E.g. if you have a main branch `main` and a feature branch `my-feature` and you create a pull request from `my-feature` onto `main`, then the Git history could look like this:

```
                       main
                        ↓
* --- * --- * --- * --- *
             \
              \--- * --- * --- *
                               ↑
                           my-feature
```

Both branches could have diverged which means that the latest commit on `my-feature` no longer represents the state of the code that it would be once you merge the feature branch in.

So Azure DevOps is smart here and merges your changes once first in order to test the state of the code of the merged result. So it effectively does this:

```
                       main
                        ↓
* --- * --- * --- * --- * ------ M
             \                  /
              \--- * --- * --- *
                               ↑
                           my-feature
```

The pipeline will then run on the merge commit `M`. You can see that if you click on the commit within the build pipeline run. The name of the commit should be something like *“Merge pull request 123 from my-feature into main“*.

Now, of course, the main branch could still progress after you have created the pull request. So there is a functionality to explicitly *redo* the merge in order to trigger a re-evaluation. You can access that option from the pull request’s menu:

[image: Additional options in Azure DevOps pull request]

The option “Restart merge” will ask Azure DevOps to redo the merge with the latest state of the target branch (i.e. `main`). Depending on the result, this may cause an automatic rebuild then, to reevaluate the pipeline result on the latest version.

Comment: ADO will create this merge-commit *even if the source branch is downstream of the destination branch*. This is preventing me from being able to do some nice de-duplication of work between my one pipeline that gates merges to `dev` and my other pipeline that checks the status of `dev` -- since in the latter run I cannot look up by commit-hash the artifacts created by the earlier run, for reuse. Unless I want to tell my whole department that they can't do fast-forward merges of PRs.

Comment: @KeithRussell Depending on your versioning strategy you would want to avoid reusing pipeline runs anyway. You probably wouldn’t want to ship a version that includes some feature branch details even if it is fundamentally the same code being built.